# How to call API only once with React Query?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm making a visitor call system with React Query.

I have a kind of call (button) and I want to call the api only when it is pressed.
However, when the component is rendered, it keeps calling the api.

1. How not to call the component when it is rendered
2. How to call api only when button is pressed

What should I do?

```
//App.jsx
const query = useQuery('resData', getEmployData('datas'), {
  enabled: false
  });

const callBtn = () => {
  query.refetch()
}


return (
  <ul>
    <li onClick ={callBtn}>Post</li>
    <li>Food</li>
    <li>Other</li>
  </ul>
)
```

this is api function

```
const getEmployData = async(callKind) => {
    const {data} = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/welcome?callKind=${callKind}`);

    return data
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can achieve that by using `staleTime: Infinity` on your config object. Please take a look at https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/initial-query-data#staletime-and-initialdataupdatedat

Your code should look like:

```js
const query = useQuery('resData', getEmployData('datas'), {
  enabled: false,
  staleTime: Infinity
});
```

This will tell react query that this data should be considered as "Fresh", by default queries are marked as "Stale" right away and "Stale" queries are refetched automatically in the background when:

- New instances of the query mount
- The window is refocused
- The network is reconnected.
- The query is optionally configured with a refetch interval.

https://tanstack.com/query/v3/docs/react/guides/important-defaults

Comment: If the query fails, it will retry in this case?

Comment: By default React query will retry a failing request up to 3 times before settling on status `errored`. Whether the request ends up in `status: "success"` or `status: "error"` makes no difference to the freshness or staleness of the data. If the request is a `status: "error"` and it's considered "fresh", it will behave exactly as a `status: "success"` would do.

Comment: So you'll need `retry: false`to guarantee that it will only call API once.

Comment: Correct, I always disable retryability in react-query, you can disable it globally using the QueryClient `defaultOptions` parameters https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/reference/QueryClient

Comment: saved my day! spent hours finding where it's triggering the render 