# Use react Query Data in useEffect Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I'm using react query to fetch data to the component.i have a requiremnt to do only first time the component renders.(Set a Default value)So I thought to use fetch data of the useQuery hook inside a useEffect.But it didn't work.

Here is my code...

```
export default function Header() {
.
.
.

    //Here i'm using a custom hook
  const { data: workSpaceArray } = useWorkspacesByUserData(onFetchWorkspaceSuccess, onFetchWorkspaceError);
  
   useEffect(() => {
   const defaultWorkspaceItem = workSpaceArray?.data.info.workspaces.filter(workspace => workspace.name === workSpaceArray?.data.info.default_workspace_id);
   localStorage.removeItem(USER_WORKSPACE);
   localStorage.setItem(USER_WORKSPACE, JSON.stringify(defaultWorkspaceItem[0]));
   setSelectedWorkspaceValue(defaultWorkspaceItem[0].name)
 }, []);
  
  return(
  ...
  );
  
  }
```

```
Inside the custom hook...
```

```
import { useQuery, useMutation } from 'react-query'
import { protectedRequest } from '../utils/axios-utils'
import { ResponseHandler } from "./ResponseHandler"

const fetchWorkspacesByUserId = async () => {
    const response = await protectedRequest({ url: '/workspace/load' });
    return ResponseHandler(response);
}

export const useWorkspacesByUserData = (onSuccess, onError) => {
    return useQuery('fetch-workspaces-by-user', fetchWorkspacesByUserId,
        {
            onSuccess,
            onError,
            staleTime: 120000,
        })
}
```

The error I'm getting.....

[image: Erro in the console]

Can anybody give me help to fix this issue? Thank you!

Comment: You won't have any data when it is rendering for the first time, so `workSpaceArray`  will always be empty for that `useEffect`.   Just add `workSpaceArray` as a dependency.  Then to prevent refetching, set all the refetch and retry options in  `useQuery` to false and the stale time to `Infinity`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call API only once with React Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71432172/how-to-call-api-only-once-with-react-query)

Comment: @possum Thank you for looking into this problem.I followed your articles,but I'm getting the same issue that I had earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all who looked into this problem. I was able to figure it out by using refetch inside useEffect.

```js
export default function Header() {
.
.
.

    //Here i'm using a custom hook
  const { data: workSpaceArray, refetch } = useWorkspacesByUserData(onFetchWorkspaceSuccess, onFetchWorkspaceError);
  
   useEffect(() => {
   refetch();
   const defaultWorkspaceItem = workSpaceArray?.data.info.workspaces.filter(workspace => workspace.name === workSpaceArray?.data.info.default_workspace_id);
   localStorage.removeItem(USER_WORKSPACE);
   localStorage.setItem(USER_WORKSPACE, JSON.stringify(defaultWorkspaceItem[0]));
   setSelectedWorkspaceValue(defaultWorkspaceItem[0].name)
 }, []);
  
  return(
  ...
  );
  
  }
```